# cors error with nginx, node and vue when using SSL

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm using self-signed certs and nginx to get https to work on my server.
Without https I get no error. But when using https I suddenly get a cors error (firefox) / ssl protocol error (chrome). I enabled cors in my backend and in my nginx vue config.

In app.js:

```
app.options('*', cors())
app.use(cors());
// Still using http module cause nginx is doing https stuff
const listener = app.listen(nconf.get('port'), () => console.log(`Ready on port ${listener.address().port}.`));
```

node nginx conf looks like:

```
 listen       443 ssl;
 listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
 server_name  localhost;

 # point to ssl certificate path
 include snippets/bcknd/self-signed.conf;
 include snippets/bcknd/ssl-params-bck.conf;
 root /var/www/server/pvapp-server;

 location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:60702;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_ssl_verify off;
 }
```

vue nginx config looks like:

```
     listen       443 ssl http2;
     listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
     server_name  inf-education-67.umwelt-campus.de;

     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

     # point to ssl certificate path
     include snippets/self-signed.conf;
     include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

     location / {
         # point to dist folder inside vue source code folder
         root /var/www/client/pvapp-client/dist;
         autoindex on;
         autoindex_exact_size off;
         index index.html index.htm;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;


     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
  }
```

Comment: "I suddenly get a cors error" — Which says what, exactly?

Comment: "ssl protocol error" — Which says what, exactly?

Comment: @Quentin The errors are that vaguely `myip:60702/user/login:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` or `Cross-source (cross-origin) request blocked: The same-source rule prohibits reading the external resource at https://myip:60702/user/login. (Reason: CORS request failed).`

Comment: Request the URL directly. Type it into the address bar. It may give you more information about the SSL error.

Comment: @Quentin Postman is giving me:
`Error: write EPROTO 1284230808:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:` or clearer with curl:
`curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an SSL error from `myip:60702` but your code says `proxy_pass http://localhost:60702` so that port isn't running an SSL service. It is plain HTTP.

You need to make the HTTPS request to the URL which actually uses HTTPS.

Comment: If I change my backend calls back to http in axios I get: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://inf-education-67.umwelt-campus.de/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint `

Comment: That's why I said "make the HTTPS request to the URL which actually uses HTTPS" and not "bypass your nginx server completely and request directly from node"

Comment: So I need to change the baseURL in axios? What URL would I need to use then when requesting from nginx?

Comment: What's the URL to your nginx server? Presumably you are already using it to load the original HTML document.

Comment: Using the standard URL in the server_name like `https://inf-education-67...` is giving me a 404. And sorry for the dumb questions but I'm totally new to this nginx stuff.

Comment: You wrote the configuration for your nginx proxy server. You should know the URL to it.

Comment: Well, it's just running on localhost. But that's not working.